# Using Variables as Parameter Names

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

Let's say I want to make a JavaScript function which sets variables to numbers, using the following format. It would not work, but why exactly? How could it be made to work?

```
function variableSet(varName, varValue) {
    varName = varValue;
}
```

The idea is to create a variable with the name used as a parameter, and give it the value of the second parameter. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question. But if you need to give a variable name and it's value to overwrite the variable, it can be done like that:

```
this[varName]=varValue;
```

In this case "this" is your context, in which variable was defined. If you need to provide the other context, you can put it as other parameter, so function will look like this:

```
function variableSet(varName, varValue, context) {
    context[varName]=varValue;
```

Comment: The question was how to create a function which creates global variables. For example, if you called the function with the following: `variableSet(message, "Hello World");` it would be equivalent to this: `message = "Hello World";`

Comment: if you provide string as the first arguement, it will do what you ask. I mean like that: variableSet("message", "Hello World");

Comment: I used the following code:                                              `function variableSet(varName, varValue) {
        varName = varValue;
    }
    variableSet("message", "hi");
    alert("Message Coming...");
    alert(message);`       It opened two alerts, the first saying "Message Coming..." as expected, the second blank

Comment: What should I use as `context` when I call the function?

Comment: I used `this` and the alert message was "undefined"

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one last question for you. When you call the context 'this' in the jsfiddle, is the context global or local to the function, because since the function is called in the global scope, 'this' could be global. But since it is used within the function, 'this' could be local.

Comment: in that jsfiddle its the one, that is outside of the function. So in case you have function defined in global, this will point to window.